# How to change an array passed to a function without iterating through its items in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, arguments, pass-by-reference

I have a function that accepts an array a its first argument. Within this function, a second array is constructed. I want the passed array be replaced by the new array. Is it possible to change the original array without changing its items one-by-one?

```
var myFunct=function(arr){
   var arr2=[];
   for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
      arr2.push(2 * arr[i]);
   arr=arr2;
}
var arr=[1,2,3];
myFunc(arr);
console.log(arr);
//displays [1,2,3] not the desired [2,4,6];
```

If I change the function so that all items of `arr` change separately, the function operate as I want. Why is it so? Is it a way to change `arr` by simply assigning it to the new array?

```
//works fine
var myFunct=function(arr){
   var arr2=[];
   for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
      arr2.push(2 * arr[i]);
   //arr=arr2;
   for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
      arr[i]=arr2[i];   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it a requirement that you mutate in-place? Why not just return the new array?

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];

function myFunc(a) {
  return a.map(item => item*2);
}

arr = myFunc(arr);

console.log(arr); // [2, 4, 6]
```

---

**Direct answer:** no, you can't do that. `arr` inside your function refers to the local variable *inside* the function. In order to change the contents of that array *outside* the function, you need to individually update its entries.

Comment: This function already exists and returns another value, so I prefer to change the passed variable

Comment: @ormoz You could easily do `var arr = myFunc([1, 2, 3])` in that case... The `map` function is _ideal_ for your purposes and you are simply nitpicking about the fact that it is a copy...

Comment: @ormoz I'm confused by your comment; if the function already exists, how do you intend to change its behavior?

Comment: Thanks @Mathletics It already exists for another reason, but now, I want to get the newly computed array from this function (avoiding to write a new function to compute `arr` )

Comment: Yeah, I still don't understand what you're trying to do.